# Unable to instantiate application - ClassNotFoundException on MainActivity

Tags: android, classnotfound

I've tried cleaning my project several times, restarting Eclipse, going to Build path -> Export, making sure Android private libraries is ticked, and I've tried parsing through XML and Java files to find the error myself. I have also tried researching here on StackOverflow but to no avail.

I've also checked if I was calling things before the `onCreate` method.

I fear my manifest XML file might be causing an issue but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Also a little information about the project which may help you find the bug:

1. Java files are located in the Java package `com.example.myfirstapp`.
2. The "Schedule" and "MainActivity" XML files are located in `layout` directory.

Since the error is related to the MainActivity XML file, I'll post that and the manifest.

So here's my `MainActivity` XML file (file name is activity_main.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#800000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">        
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@+string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/brock_logo"/>    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textWebPassword"/>    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:text="@string/login" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest` XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>    
    <application
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hasCode="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/brock_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/brock_logo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.Schedule"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here is my `Logcat` output:

```
09-21 13:19:41.598: D/dalvikvm(1190): Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-21 13:19:41.690: D/AndroidRuntime(1190): Shutting down VM
09-21 13:19:41.690: W/dalvikvm(1190): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0xa4d85b20)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1190
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4317)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib]]
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
09-21 13:19:41.698: E/AndroidRuntime(1190):     ... 11 more
```

Sorry for dumping code and debug output. Just trying to provide as much information as possible.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You have the package fully declared for the Schedule, and not for the MainActivity. Are you sure Main Activity is in that package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/brock_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/brock_logo"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

This tells Android that you want to create Application instance. You don't need that class in your app.

Comment: Sorry I might be misinterpreting what you are trying to say. Are you saying I don't need the MainActivity.java file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you   actually SHOULD tick use android private libraries. also I was having same problem because of using wrong appcompat library. Make sure everything is OK with it.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, dumb typo. All the libraries in output and export are ticked.

Comment: well, try right clicking your src folder>build path>use as source.